# 1 to 1 relationship core data iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, entity-relationship, iphonecoredatarecipes

I have two entities: Login (user id, password) and Information (title, info).
Now there is a 1 to 1 relation between them.
I need to add some information in the database unique to a user.

My code is below here:

```
    Login *information = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Login"
                                                      inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    information.information.title = informationTitleTextView.text;
    information.information.info_1 = information1textview.text;
    information.information.info_2 = information2textview.text;

    [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];  // write to database

    [self.delegate savebuttontapped:self];
```

But It's not Working.I don't Know, What i am doing wrong?Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's certainly confusing that you name your instance of Login as `information`. Also, if this code is executing, then clearly *something* is happening, not *nothing*, so it'd help if you explained what you expect to happen that isn't. It'd also help if you didn't ignore the error that `-save:` may be returning -- how hard is it to pass the address of a NSError pointer?

Comment: i want that the values be assigned to the attributes... but when iam doing NSLog and checking it is showing NULL and nothing is getting written into data base...

Comment: Please consider using the keychain to store authentication details.  This is what it is designed for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't added an instance of `Information` to the context. Try this:

```
Login *login = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Login" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
Information *information = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Information" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

login.information = information;
login.information.title = informationTitleTextView.text;
//...and so on...
```

Of course, if you're going to fetch a Login object based on its attributes, you'll want to actually store something in those attributes:

```
login.userId = theUserId;
login.password = thePassword;
```

At some point in the future, you'll probably want to fetch just the Login object that matches your criteria. Once you have that, you can get the associated information object without any trouble:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Login"
    inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userId like %@ AND password like %@", theUserId, thePassword];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
NSError *err = nil;
NSArray *matchingLogins = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&err];
int count = [matchingLogins count];
if (count != 1) {
    NSLog(@"Houston, we have a problem.");
}
Login *login = [matchingLogins objectAtIndex:0];
Information *info = login.information; // Notice: no separate fetch needed
```

Comment: Thanks...that solved my problem. on the same lines now i want to fetch the information.title and display it unique to that login.

Comment: // Configure the cell...
    

  Login *login;
login = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    Information *information;
    information = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    login.information=information;
    cell.textLabel.text = login.information.title;
    return cell;
}

Comment: @user1253637 You don't need to fetch the Information object separately -- it's already associated with the Login object, so when you get the Login you've already got the Information too. See my updated answer for a different way to fetch just the one Login that matches your user's ID and password. Not super useful if you're trying to display all the users, but it may be instructive.

Comment: The attributes login.userId ,login.password have values when the user does add an account and it gets stored in the data base. I am taking user input and comparing whether the user has entered it correct and if yes, then  it should be able to display the information.title related to only that user. This last part is not happening.